# Facebook application load testing

Tags: facebook, load-testing

How can i make load testing to facebook application?
Facebook prohibits the use of automated tools!!!

Answer (score 3):

You should just load test your code, not Facebook's. Your app should be an iframe app, so it shouldn't be hard to load test outside of the Facebook platform. Just disable the Facebook calls.

Facebook has a much bigger setup than you and can handle a much larger load than your load testing tools could probably generate. And if Facebook is having load issues, there is nothing you can do about it anyway.

I've been developing Facebook apps for about 3 years. Facebook does have issues fairly often, but there is nothing you can do in your app except add error capture, retry and/or recovery.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a tool called FriendRunner (www.friendrunner.com) which will allow you to load test a Facebook app WITHOUT modifying it, so you don't have to comment out any API calls. This will give you the most authentic results.

They can also simulate all kinds of strange situations and problems with the Facebook API so you can see how robust your application really is.

Comment: I'm just googling around the subject now and found your FriendRunner site too. The  product looks useful, but the lack of pricing or even trial usage plans on there scared me off.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to decouple your app from Facebook for the purposes of load testing?  You can probably assume that the facebook platform can handle everything you throw at it, so you really just need to test your custom code.  Once this works without any load problems, you should be good to go (assuming you can properly deal with unusual cases like facebook being down/the api being down).

Answer (score 0):

We've used the approach suggested by [Brent Baisley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151269/brent-baisley) and it's a good approach, but I've always begrudged the extra work of toggling FB apis to test the app.  We are trying an approach right now that should allow you to load test most apps directly in the FB canvas.

From Facebook themselves: "[You can use test users for manual or automated testing.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/)"

You can also pre-authorize test users with specific permissions to your app so there's no issue of getting stuck at the permissions dialog.  In the FB response, you'll get a URL that allows you to login with that test user.  With one or many of these URLs in hand, easy enough to use something like Seige or Apache Bench to automate your load testing of your Facebook App in its normal environment.